# Adding and Subtracting vectors

Tags: vectors

[image]

*I'm stuck on this question. I've tried to draw the diagram and then draw out the sum diagram and the only two possible answers I got was either part a) or b). But I don't know which one is right. I've been stuck on this question for so long that I'd appreciate anyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

Start at $D$ and walk round to $C$ via all the others. If you start on a particular path at the tail of an arrow, count that vector as positive, if you start at the head, count it negative. So, in $DE$, we start at the head of the arrow, so that's $-a$, then $EF$ starts at the tail, so that's $+b$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The resultant vector you want is $\vec w$. Think of a resultant vector as the shortest path between two points. You start with its tail and proceed to its head, travelling in the direction of the vector's arrow.

The equivalent (in vector terms) would be to take a longer walk from the same starting point to the same ending point via a different path. Note that equivalence here means start at the same start point, and ending at the same end point. Length of path doesn't matter. This is how a vector can be expressed as the sum of other vectors, you need this intuitive understanding.

So here you're starting at $D$ and need to end up at $C$. Instead of going immediately along $DC$, an equivalent path would be $DEFABC$ (in strict order). Since this is multiple choice, we can immediately eliminate the incorrect possibilities, so we're left only with options $1,3, 4$.

You just need to figure out the vectors corresponding to that alternate path. Now $\vec {DE}$ is going opposite to the direction of $\vec a$, so the first vector you need is $-\vec a$ (the reverse of $\vec a$).

The second segment you need is $\vec {EF}$, which means going along $\vec b$ in its current direction, so you need to add $+\vec b$. But all options $1,3,4$ have this bit correct, so this is not very helpful.

Now proceed to $\vec {FA}$, which means going in reverse to $\vec c$. So you need to add $-\vec c$. This immediately allows you to narrow the possibilities down to simply option $1$.

You should confirm this option is correct by working on the last two segments yourself.